PrimeFaces InputNumber is changing value type in webpage after losing focus
I'm having an issue with one of the PrimeFaces inputNumber component. It seems that, after losing the hover of the component, the type of the value inside the inputNumber change from a decimal to a integer number. The value is setted from the backend and it's rounded up in order to show two decimals max.
For example, if the inputNumber receive the value "412,09", after losing focus on the component the value will change to "41.209". Checking the value component in the inspector shows that the value is unchanged (412.08500).
Here's the component.
<p:inputNumber widgetVar="pago"
               onblur="PF('pago').setValue(PF('pago').getValue().replace('.', ','));"
               padControl="true"
               value="#{pago.importe}"
               thousandSeparator="."
               decimalSeparator=","
               decimalPlaces="2"
               minValue="0"
               maxValue="#{movimientoBeans.movimiento.importeCliente}"
               disabled="#{pago.pagosTipos != null}"
               autocomplete="off" />

What can be the origin of the issue or bug and how it can be solved? The field should be changable if the user wished for. So it's not a solution disable="true" the component. Deleting onBlur attribute won't solve the bug.
I tried using an AJAX event, javascript function inside the component and forcing the value type, using the convertNumber component and it didn't work.

What's the page's default locale? Check faces-config.xml. Looks like it isn't Spanish at all. As a quick test, wrap entire page in <f:view locale="es"> and retry. Don't forget to remove the onblur / thousandSeparator / decimalSeparator, all of these are unnecessary if the page locale is configured correctly.

Default locale is set in "es_AR". Adding a <f:view locale="es"> and deleting the unnecessary attributes doesn't fix the issue.

What version of PrimeFaces?

Did you check the maxValue in your class (importeCliente variable)? Even I had faced this issue where the value wasn't rounded up, and after losing focus it was changed to maxValue.

@Melloware the PrimeFaces version is v10... Yes, I checked and it seems that it doesn't influence the value because the value of the inputNumber goes up even if ther's a maxValue.

Can you put together a PrimeFaces Test reproducer so we can debug?  See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test
